Copying subfolders to a new directory and renaming them to the previous parent folders name
I have about 2000 folders that I need to move and am looking for a bit of a better way than just copy/pase the rename.
Current folder structure is like this Job>Asset>Reports.  What I am trying to do is consolidate all of the reports folders (and all of the files) under a single folder, and rename just the Reports folder to the Asset name.
Currently in my test folder I have this code working to copy over the folder and contents, but I can't get it to rename so it just fails after copying over the first folder.
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Test Source" -include "Reports" -recurse |
    Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Test Destination" -recurse -container |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Parent.Name}

I'm assuming that the issues is somewhere in how I am setting up the Rename-Item, as it's not renaming the folder after it's copied to the new location. I also don't want to rename the report folders in the original path, just the new one.
Thanks for the help!

Welcome to SO.
Please format your code properly using a [code block]. Thanks in advance.

Well, after spending 2 hours trying to figure it out, I figured it out 5 minutes after finally posting the question.....
Solution was to ignore the Rename-Item feature completely and just use join-path
Working code is as follows.
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Test Source" -include "Reports" -recurse | Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path "C:\Test Destination" ("$($_.Parent.Name)")} -recurse -container 

I'll leave this up as a sign of shame, and to hopefully help out anyone with a similar query, as I couldn't find a good answer for this anywhere and had to piece together a few different solutions.

Please format your code properly using the code box feature within the editor.
